# How can I delete old file contents right before a new test?

Tags: python, numpy, logfile

I have a Python Numpy program that prints time and voltage readings into a 'logfile.txt'. The program works fine but I would like it to automatically delete all the data in the old file before a new test of voltages. The new time and voltage readings would then be printed into a blank 'logfile.txt'. I currently have to delete the file later on, then create a new blank file in Idle with the same name, 'logfile.txt'. The pertinent lines of my current program are:

```
    logfile = open('logfile.txt', 'a')  
    print >> logfile, time(), (volts)  
    logfile.close()
```

Thanks, Rico

Answer (score 1):

Just open in 'w' mode. That will truncate the file.

```
logfile = open('logfile.txt', 'w')  
print >> logfile, time(), (volts)  
logfile.close()
```

Comment: I tried replacing the 'a' with 'w' but now the logfile only has one time and voltage reading. Using 'a' I would get a continuous time/volts reading every .45 seconds and this would be printed on successive lines in the 'logfile.txt' until I stop the program.

Comment: @Rico Then only open the file once, at the top of your program, and then don't close it till the end of your program.

Comment: @SethMMorton is absolutely right. Either keep an open file object or only use 'w' once at the start of your program.

Comment: Thanks guys. I finally got the it to work, but I had to put the 'w' line at the very end of my program. I still keep the 'a' line towards the beginning.

Comment: @Rico - 'w' truncates the file and you will lose all logged data when you do it. If you really are appending throughout your program and truncating at the end, the file will be empty when the program exits.